# Javascript breaking up string and reverse it

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to break up a sting to groups of five and reverse each one individually. I want it to work for any string, (there is no delimiter for splitting)

For example, if the variable is:

> Iwanttobreakthisintogroupsoffiveandreverse

I would want it to return:

> tnawI erbot ihtka otnis puorg iffos dnaev rever es

How do I go about this?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Homework assignment question, I presume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var input="Iwanttobreakthisintogroupsoffiveandreverse";
var matches = input.match(/.{1,5}/g);
for (i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
    matches[i] = matches[i].split("").reverse().join("");
}
alert(matches);
```

It pops up `tnawI,erbot,ihtka,otnis,puorg,iffos,dnaev,rever,es`

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Iwanttobreakthisintogroupsoffiveandreverse"
var result = [];
str.replace(/.{1,5}/g, function(m) {
    result.push(m.split('').reverse().join(''));
});
result.join(' ');
// "tnawI erbot ihtka otnis puorg iffos dnaev rever es"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var chars = "Iwanttobreakthisintogroupsoffiveandreverse".split('')
var str_rev = []

for (i = 0; i < chars.length; i += 5)
    str_rev.push( chars.slice(i, i + 5).reverse().join('') )
```

1. Convert to char array using `split('')`. This allows you to use array methods like `reverse` and `slice`
2. Loop through the char array taking 5 element slices
3. `reverse` the elements, `join` the chars to create a string, and add it to `rev_str`

Comment: `str_rev` needs to be initialized. `.concat()` needs to be `.push()`, and you need to remove the space from the quotes in `.join()`

Comment: k thanks, I'm not all that familiar with javascript.